# Inheritable properties - Why don't anonymous block boxes inherit the property?

Tags: html, css, w3c

According to the documentation:

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level

> The properties of anonymous boxes are inherited from the **enclosing
> non-anonymous box** (e.g., in the example just below the subsection
> heading "Anonymous block boxes", the one for DIV). Non-inherited
> properties have their initial value. For example, the font of the
> anonymous box is inherited from the DIV, but the margins will be 0.

CSS:

```css
p {
  display: inline
}

span {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<P style="text-align: center;">
  <!--enclosing non-anonymous box  -->
  This is anonymous text before the SPAN - according to the specification it should inherit the text-align: center; property of p, because p is the enclosing non-anonymous box of this anonymous block box
  <SPAN>This is the content of SPAN.</SPAN>
  <!-- Only this is centered -->
  This is anonymous text after the SPAN - according to the specification it should inherit the text-align: center; property of p, because p is the enclosing non-anonymous box of this anonymous block box
</P>
<!--enclosing non-anonymous box  -->
```

Anonymous block boxes are not centered, only the `span`.
but I do comment this CSS:

```
/* p { 
    display: inline 
  }
span { 
    display: block 
} */
```

it seems that it inherits it, the anonymous block boxes is centered.

So, the question is, **what exactly does the rule refer to? An example would help me, please**

I am very confused

Considering another example: If I keep applying `display: inline;` to `p` and test the `color: red;` property, it is inherited, i.e. all the text turns red (**including anonymous block boxes**)

Comment: You set `p` to `display: inline`, which wasn’t part of the deal.

Comment: I think what you are saying is not entirely true, in my humble opinion, with respect @Ry-

Comment: why inside `p` can we put a `span` with `display: block`? @Temani Afif. As far as I know, inline elements cannot contain block-elements.

Comment: Thanks @Temani Afif+1, one last question, the anonymous box is inline because `p` is `display: inline` (inline formatting context), right? If `p` were `display: block;` it would be anonymous block box, right?

Comment: Excellent @Temani Afif +1. Now I understand, I wasn't **sure** why you said the anonymous box was inline.

Comment: hi @Temani Afif - Why is it an anonymous inline box? - "*did you consider the nature of the anonymous box? It's not a block one but an inline one and it does inherit the text-align but text-align on inline box (either anonymous or not) doesn't have any effect*"

Answer (score 1):

The confusion probably arises from the style rules being distributed across the stylesheet and markup.

Notice that, when combining all of the styles for `p`, you get `display: inline; text-align: center;`. Imagine trying to put `text-align: center;` on a `<em>` tag: what would centered alignment even mean?

You are correct that, in the linked spec, the `p` tag does get an inline display, for the sake of demonstrating how inline elements get "split" around block children. To see how the styles are inherited, I recommend applying a border, as the spec mentions in a subsequent paragraph:

> Properties set on elements that cause anonymous block boxes to be generated still apply to the boxes and content of that element. For example, if a border had been set on the P element in the above example, the border would be drawn around C1 (open at the end of the line) and C2 (open at the start of the line).

See the clarified inline CSS on the divs, along with the border example, in the following snippet:

```css
p {
  display: inline
}

span {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block; text-align: center;">Block display, centered text</div>
<div style="display: inline; text-align: center;">Inline display, centered text</div>

<hr>

<P style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <!--enclosing non-anonymous box  -->
  This is anonymous text before the SPAN - according to the specification it should inherit the text-align: center; property of p, because p is the enclosing non-anonymous box of this anonymous block box
  <SPAN>This is the content of SPAN.</SPAN>
  <!-- Only this is centered -->
  This is anonymous text after the SPAN - according to the specification it should inherit the text-align: center; property of p, because p is the enclosing non-anonymous box of this anonymous block box
</P>
<!--enclosing non-anonymous box  -->
```